# Como usar uma especie de getText().toString() do Java em HTML com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Como fazer pra pegar o que é digitado numa caixa de texto HTML usando JavaScript, assim como funciona o `getText().toString()` em Java?

Comment: Podes explicar o que queres dizer com _"Caixa de texto HTML"_? Podes mostrar o HTML?

Comment: Uma input no meu caso = <input type="text">

Comment: `var texto = document.querySelector('input').value;` <- isso lê o valor do primeiro input que encontrar na página, o método aceita seletores CSS, neste caso use um simples: `input`. É isso que procuras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer isto. Mas tem várias outras formas, depende do que deseja.

```js
function getText() {
  input = document.getElementById('campo') //pega o elemento
  console.log(input.value); //pega o valor do elemento
}
```

```html
<input type = "text" value = "texto aqui" id = "campo"/>
<input type = "button" value = "ok" onclick="getText();"/>
```

Documentação do [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). O segredo é o uso desta função de API do DOM do navegador. Ele pega um elemento do documento sendo analisado pelo nome. O nome é definido pelo `id` colocado na *tag* HTML.

Pode fazer assim também, como eu disse, depende da necessidade.

```html
<input type = "text" value = "texto aqui" id = "campo"/>
<input type = "button" value = "ok" onclick="console.log(document.getElementById('campo').value);"/>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/DOM/ProcessOnTime.js).

Pode fazer algo mais complexo.

Comment: Sim é isso que eu procurava, muito obrigado!